# Java: Unsorted Array to Descending Sorted Array

Tags: java

I am a beginner learning java and I am trying to transfer the variables in an array to another array in descending order. This is my code:

```
    int num[] = new int[6];
    int DecSort[] = new int[6];
    System.out.println("Input 6 numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        num[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    //sorted array is descending
    int max = num[0];
    int maxpos = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (num[i] > max) {
                max = num[i];
                maxpos = i;
            }
        }
        DecSort[j] = max;
        max = num[0];
        num[maxpos] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    System.out.println("sorted array");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(DecSort[i]);
    }
```

When I input 213, 45, 1234, 765, 23, 5 as the array, it outputs:
sorted array
1234
765
213
213
213
213

I am not sure where my mistake is, please help!

Comment: The Java naming convention, which you will want to follow, requires that members, static methods, and local variables be spelled out in camel case, i.e. the first letter should be in lower case.

Comment: change `max = num[0]` to `max = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're initializing `max` to `num[0]`. This means that any number in the array smaller than the first will never be found, because `num[i] > max` will always be `false`. You could fix it by setting your initial value of `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

However, are you aware that the Java Standard Library already has sort functionality. You could use that to sort you array in ascending order, and then just print it in reverse:

```
int num[] = new int[6];
System.out.println("Input 6 numbers: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}

Arrays.sort(num);

System.out.println("sorted array");
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; --i) {
    System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

I'll leave you to work out how to turn an ascending array into a descending one if that's what you need. ;)

---

Alternatively, using a `NavigableSet`, you can even get Java to sort it for you on the fly:

```
NavigableSet<Integer> nums = new TreeSet<>();
System.out.println("Input 6 numbers: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    nums.add(Integer.valueOf(br.readLine()));
}

Integer[] sortedNums = nums.descendingSet().toArray(new Integer[6]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed just a few your code:

1 - Removed ***DecSort*** array beacause its not needed.

2 - Applied bubble sort descending algorithm.

3 - Change de break condition to the ***for*** in order to be used for any size array.

Have a look:

```
public void orderDescending() {
    int num[] = { 213, 45, 1234, 765, 23, 5 };
    // sorted array is descending
    int maxpos = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
        for (int i = j; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) {
                int tempA = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = tempA;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("sorted array");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }
}
```

Just a few changes and works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Can create Comparator and that can be control your ascending and descending order.

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    };

    // option 1
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 1, 24, 4, 4, 345 };
    Arrays.sort(array, comparator);
```